# C# populate array with unique ints No Linq or ArrayLists;

Tags: c#, arrays

This code is buggy but can't figure out why ... want to populate an array with 7 unique random integers without using arraylists or linq! I know the logic is not okay...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    int current;
         int[] numbers = new int[7];  // size of that array 
         Random rNumber = new Random();
         current = rNumber.Next(1, 50);
         numbers[0] = current;
         Console.WriteLine("current number is {0}", current);
         for (int i=1;i<7;i++)
         {
             current = rNumber.Next(1, 50);
             for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
             {
                 do
                 {
                     if (current == numbers[j])
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("Duplicate Found");
                         current = rNumber.Next(1, 50);
                     }
                     else
                     {   
                         numbers[j++] = current;
                         break;
                     }
                 }while (current == numbers[j]);

             }//inner for

         }//outer for
         for (int l = 0; l < 7; l++) // DISPLAY NUMBERS
         {
             Console.WriteLine(numbers[l]);
         }

    }// main
 }//class
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are looking for random numbers, so the other answer is not what you are looking for.

There are a couple of issues here.

- The inner loop is testing for duplicates.  However, it is looking from 0 through the end of the array since it is using `numbers.length`.  This should probably be `i`, to compare with already set values.  `numbers.length` is always 7 regardless of whether or not you set any of the elements.
- the assignment is using j, so presuming the first element is not a duplicate, it will be overwritten each time.  That should be `numbers[i] = current;`.  No ++ necessary as the `for` is handling the incrementing.
- if you determine that a number is a duplicate, j should be reset to zer to check against the entire list again rather than having the while in the middle.

Without a complete rewrite, the changes will look something like this:

```
     for (int i=1;i<7;i++)
     {
         current = rNumber.Next(1, 50);
         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)  //----------------- loop through set values
         {
             if (current == numbers[j])
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Duplicate Found");
                 current = rNumber.Next(1, 50);
                 j = 0; // -----------------------reset the counter to start over
             }
         }//inner for

         // if we got here there is no duplicate --------------------------------
         numbers[i] = current;

     }//outer for
```

(Please note that I have not tested this code, just added the changes)

Comment: tested it out i totally forgot about resetting j to 0 ,

Answer (score 4):

> want to populate an array with 7 unique integers without using
>   arraylists or linq!

```
int[] list = new int[7];
for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
    list[i] = i;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I changed your inner loop, if the random number is already in the array; create a new random and reset j to 0.

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            current = rNumber.Next(1, 50);
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (current == numbers[j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate Found");
                    current = rNumber.Next(1, 50);
                    j = 0; // reset the index iterator
                }
            }//inner for
            numbers[i] = current; // Store the unique random integer
        }//outer for
```

Comment: We all know that the OP meant 7 unique **random** integers, however this is certainly the best answer to the question that was **actually** asked. +1

Comment: I meant Random gentlemen my apologies

Comment: Downvoters, please explain your hate. Or explain where I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: It is not generating random numbers between 1 and 50 and there is no garanties that there is no duplicates.

Comment: @Casperah, where is 1, 50 a requirement?

Comment: The example code states rNumber.Next(1, 50) meaning an integer >= 1 and < 50.

Answer (score 1):

you keep overwriting the same indexes in the else, and also checking too many indices causing the first to show up as a duplicate at all times which was false...

change it to:

```
 for (int i=1;i<7;i++)
 {
     current = rNumber.Next(1, 50);

     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)    ///< change to j < i.  no need to check the others
     {
         do
         {
             if (current == numbers[j])
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Duplicate Found");
                 current = rNumber.Next(1, 50);
             }
             else
             {   
                 numbers[i] = current;   ///< not j++ but i to prevent writing at the same locations over and over again
                 break;
             }
         }while (current == numbers[j]);
     }//inner for
 }//outer for
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
int[] list = new int[7]; 
var rn = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
{ 
    var next = rn.Next(1, 50);
    while(Contains(list, next))
    {
        next = rn.Next(1, 50);
    }
    list[i] = next;       
} 


private bool Contains(IEnumerable<int> ints, int num) 
{
    foreach(var i in ints)
    {
        if(i = num) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be getting a new value while(Contains(next)) instead of !contains?

Comment: Adding the second function improves readability considerably.

Comment: Excellent and simple, but maybe use rNumber.Next(1, 50) instead.